# operator new

Tags: c++

Вот такой вопрос для любителей С++ in depth.

Приходилось кому-либо в своих проектах определять собственный operator new, operator new[] и т.п. или встречать в чужом коде? Если да, то с какой целью это было сделано?

Comment: malloc считается?

Comment: Хотя, если речь идет о нестандартной реализации, то было бы интересно.

Comment: @mikillskegg, вообще-то их было две. Одну я точно не найду, но это был настоящий malloc()/free()/..., работавший с sbrk() на VAX-11 в BSD 4.3. Мне просто было интересно сравнить алгоритмы выделения памяти из списка расщепляемых-сливающихся блоков с разделением по нескольким пулам по размеру блока с применяемым в bsd libc алгоритмом (насколько помню "метод близнецов").

Другая реализация (код нашел) для hp-ux была простой оберткой (даже имена my_malloc/my_free...) над системным. Ее делал по требованию безопасников для обнуления освобождаемой памяти. Идея (места мало) список взятых блоков и т.п

Comment: Если интересно (IMHO не слишком, т.к. тривиально) могу завтра подробно расписать.

Comment: Спасибо, понял идею. Сам как-то для баловства написал malloc на ассемблере. Но в С++ своя специфика. Тут работа с объектами и все такое.

Comment: Да, насчет специфики согласен.

Answer (score 7):

Я переопределяю new/delete **в расширениях ПО**, т.е. в динамических библиотеках, в которых используется `STL` и/или библиотеки, наследующие ее модель динамической памяти.

Думаю, проблема "многокучности" известная, когда при инициализации `CRT`, в каждом модуле создается своя куча, которой пользуются глобальные методы управления памятью.

Вот, чтобы расширения могли свободно интегрироваться **во всех** модулях ПО, и переопределяются операторы new/delete. Для этого, основной модуль экспортирует 2 метода, в которых вызывает `malloc` и `free`, соответственно, а каждое расширение переопределяет свой new/delete, вызывая в них эти 2 метода.

Получается, что если расширения используют только глобальные new/delete, **они все используют только одну кучу**.

А для корректной работы статических объектов, использующих кучу при инициализации, я перекрываю точку входа в DLL, импортируя эти 2 метода **перед инициализацией CRT**, после чего передаю управление встроенной `_DllMainCRTStartup`. Но есть нюанс, кторый нужно учесть при такой подстановке: первое, что нужно вызвать в точке входа - `__security_init_cookie()`:

```
BOOL WINAPI MyDllStartup( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved ){
    __security_init_cookie();
    if( !::MyDllMainPreCRTStartup( hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpReserved ) ){
        return FALSE;
    }
    return _DllMainCRTStartup( hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpReserved );
}
```

p.s.: вместо `malloc` и `free` можно вызывать глобальные new/delete, это уже не принципиально.

Comment: Очень серьезно.

Comment: Да, очень серьезно, и времени на это решение тоже тогда ушло не мало. На RSDN'е я даже подинмал дискуссию о полезности такого подхода, но, по всей видимости, был банально не понят :)

Comment: - Круто.

- Какую практическую задачу вы решали таким образом? Чем не устроил дефолтный подход с использованием раздельных `heap'ов` для `dll'ок`?

- На первый взгляд, кажется, что в случае вашего подхода любое кривое расширение, которое каким-то образом `заcorrupt'ит` `heap`, вызовет крэш всего приложения (от которого в случае раздельных хипов можно было бы восстановиться).

- Что, кстати, происходит, если код в расширении вызывает `malloc / free` вместо `new / delete`?

Comment: >Какую практическую задачу вы решали таким образом? Чем не устроил дефолтный подход с использованием раздельных heap'ов для dll'ок?

Дефолтный подход подразумевает, что все объекты модулей никогда не выйдут за пределы своих модулей, в моем случае, объект можно выделить в одном модуле, а освободить - в другом и это не вызовет ошибку.

>которое каким-то образом заcorrupt'ит heap, вызовет крэш всего приложения, от которого в случае раздельных хипов можно было бы восстановиться.

Честно говоря, не верю, что обычное ПО сможет корректно продолжить работу, если одно из его расширений крашит кучу.

Comment: >Что, кстати, происходит, если код в расширении вызывает malloc / free вместо new / delete?

В этом случае используется локальная куча. Поэтому я и пишу о модели памяти `STL`, которая использует только глобальные `new/delete`. Вобщем-то многокучность - не только проблема освобождения объекта, даже простое обращение к размеру "чужого" блока памяти сгенерит исключение, на сколько помню.

Comment: Впечатлило.

Answer (score 4):

Было дело. Переопределял new для подсчета выделяемой памяти. Помнится тем же способом пытался ловить утечки памяти. И как-то пробовал писать свой менеджер памяти. В общем переопределять new скорее для развлечения. В реальных задачах это в общем-то не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Я делал такое всего один раз. Нужно было сделать кэш для объектов, о котором бы ничего не знал код, эти объекты создающий. Код был не мой, и трогать его совершенно не хотелось. Но надо было как-то пресечь постоянное пересоздание одних и тех же объектов.

В чужом коде видел такое только в книге Александреску. Он там описывал, как сделать крутой менеджер памяти для маленьких блоков. Это считается?

Comment: Спасибо. В литературе много примеров. Собственно, вопрос навеян чтением Мейерса.

Answer (score 3):

В своих. Допустим, есть такая задача: приложение должно захватывать столько памяти, сколько сказано в конфиге, не больше. Точнее даже так: при старте захатывается кусок памяти, и всё выделение идёт только внутри него. Потом, в некоторых случаях вешается сторонний CG, в некоторых - нужна своя отладка выделения/освобождения...

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал, чтобы некоторые классы размещались в специальном хранилище, которое чистится  при завершении потока. Там в деструкторах не было ничего, кроме уничтожения зависимых объектов, смысл был в том, чтобы убрать всё это крохоборство из деструкторов в менеджер памяти, который зачищает всю память оптом.

Опыт скорее не понравился. Много писанины, польза туманна.

На сегодняшний день имею мнение, что интегрировать внутрь класса логику размещения в памяти бессмысленно. Если хочешь принудить класс к работе через нестандартный менеджер памяти — закрой конструкторы и создавай экземпляры особой фабрикой. Если классу размещение не важно, нестандартный менеджер доступен через размещающий конструктор. А встраивание new/delete в класс — странная херня, смесь бульдога с крокодилом.

Сказанное не относится к переопределению глобальных new/delete, с которыми свой геморрой, но есть и польза.

Comment: Ммм. Встраивание new/delete в класс. Можно сказать я так порой делаю. Ну не совсем так. Для хранения списка выделяю большой блок памяти и постепенно его заполняю. По идее это приносит пользу, но я сейчас не припоминаю, где именно. Вроде должно быстро выделять память и удаляться.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в проектах не видел. Если не рассматривать только какие-то теоретические примеры из книг. Зачем это может понадобиться - могу представить. Например, в ситуации, когда так или иначе стандартный оператор работает неэффективно. Ну, или в целях отладки. Ведь, действительно, старую версию оператора ведь все равно можно вызвать :-)

Из (полу-)коммерческих видел свой оператор `new` в MFC.

Answer (score 0):

Да, приходилось. Но больше в embedded: дефолные реализации звали malloc()/free() тогда как нужно было использовать аллокатор RTOS (ThreadX). В другом проекте с той же RTOS был ещё и свой аллокатор с хитрой аллокацией памяти дабы уменьшить фрагментацию и сократить оверхеды на блочные выделения. Плюс тут же был простенький анализатор мемликов и логирование аллокаций.

Первый случай - проект сам поднимал, поэтому и сам писал. Второй случай - уже было сделано.

В своих были только эксперименты, что бы некоторые типы объектов выделялись из специального пула.

Из популярного, всякие valgrind подменяют вызовы new/malloc/delete/free в целях анализа утечек, повреждений.